# Teradata: Division and large decimals

Tags: decimal, overflow, teradata, division, divide

I'm trying to divide two decimal(15,2) numbers and return a high precision decimal of 15 places, but I keep getting the [2616] Numeric overflow error on anything beyond 10 decimal places, is there another way to write this to achieve a decimal result of 15 places right of the period?

select (cast(19983.74 as decimal(15,2))*1.0000000000000)/(cast(15897.40 as decimal(15,2))*1.0000000000000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more complex calculations I prefer casting the 1st operand to NUMBER, this results in the maximum possible precision:

```
SELECT Cast(19983.74 AS NUMBER)/15897.40

1.25704454816510875992300627775611106219
```

Finally cast back to whatever you need:

```
SELECT Cast(Cast(19983.74 AS NUMBER)/15897.40 AS DECIMAL(38,15))

1.257044548165109
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Teradata Documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/2AaXE45I0QMVAA9LL_kxKA). Defaults for result precision depend on MaxDecimal setting, but a CAST to something larger than MaxDecimal setting will override.

```
SELECT CAST(19983.74 AS DECIMAL(38,15))/15897.40
```